# Remove JMeter Assertion failed error

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do load test on one of our web server. I recorded a web browsing session with the chromium extension of BlazeMeter "BlazeMeter | The Load Testing Cloud 2.3.1".
After that when I run load test, I get the response code:200 for some css style sheets. But that HTTP request to retrieve the css style sheet in "view results tree" of JMeter gets RED, also the Dashboard report (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) of JMeter says, that was an assertion failed error. The response message tells about some error message as stated below:

```
Response message: Embedded resource download error:http://f...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700 code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException message:Non HTTP response message: f...content-available-to-author-only...s.com: Name or service not known,
```

How can I remove this error by editing css style sheet or how to skip this error and make it pass?
The full sample result is added below:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-01-09 11:59:45 BDT
Load time: 1031
Connect Time: 508
Latency: 764
Size in bytes: 24175
Sent bytes:1094
Headers size in bytes: 331
Body size in bytes: 23844
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: Embedded resource download error:http://f...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700 code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException message:Non HTTP response message: f...content-available-to-author-only...s.com: Name or service not known, 

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 05:59:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 21431
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 05:51:50 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "587324f6-53b7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/css
DataEncoding: null
```

Sorry, for poor language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property which controls JMeter's behavior when embedded resource download fails, by default parent sample will be marked as failed. If it is something you don't want just set `httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources` property value to `true`. It can be done in 2 ways:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
   ```
2. Pass the property via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jhttpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true -n -t ...
   ```

References:

- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)